# I keep getting this: Integrity constraint violation while trying to verify if email exists in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, xml

I'm creating a user management system. I can edit users. I can create users. I can verify that the email is in the correct format. However, my issue is with verifying if the same email exists in the database. I keep getting this error: Ouch, failed to run query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ 'Markr@fun.com' pour la clef 'email'. This code is below. The first being the form that's used store info to the database. The second being the script that's run once the submit button is pressed.

```
<?php

require("../scripts/connect.php");


if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{

    header("Location: ../hound/login.php");


    die("Redirecting to ../hound/login.php");
}

$query_parm = array(

':id' => $_GET['id']

 );


 $query = "

SELECT
*
FROM users 
WHERE 
id = :id
";


try
{
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute($query_parm);

}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{

die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

}

  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


  ?>


  <form action="../scripts/edit_users.php" method="post">

<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>

Username:<br />
<b><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b>
<br /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlentities($row['id'],  ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
First Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo `enter code he  htmlentities($row['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
<br /><br />
Last Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo htmlentities ($row['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" /> 
<br /><br />
E-Mail Address:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row     ['email'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>" /> 
<br /><br />
Password:<br />
<input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Update User" />
<a href="../scripts/users.php">Back</a><br />
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </form>
```

This is the script that's run when submit is pressed.

```
<?php


require("common.php");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{

    header("Location: ../hound/login.php");


    die("Redirecting to ../hound/login.php");
}

if(!empty($_POST))
{

if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{

    die("Please enter a valid email address...");
}

if($_POST['email'] !=$_POST['email'])
{

    $query_email = "
         SELECT email
         from users
         where
         email = :email
    ";

    $query_goes = array(

    ':email' => $_POST['email']

    );
    try
    {

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query_email);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_goes);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row) 
    {
        die("That email is already in use...");
    }

}
}


  $array_value = array(
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        ':last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
        ':id' => $_POST['id']
   );



    $query = "UPDATE users 
        SET 
        email = :email,
        first_name = :first_name, 
        last_name = :last_name

        WHERE
          id = :id
        ";


       try
    {

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($array_value);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {

        die("Ouch, failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }



    header("Location: users.php");


    die("Redirecting to users.php");

   ?>
```

Comment: `if($_POST['email'] !=$_POST['email'])`?

Comment: What are you checking with this line: if($_POST['email'] !=$_POST['email'])
?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what are you trying to do here?

```
if($_POST['email'] !=$_POST['email'])
```

That's an impossible condition. "If this thing is not itself".

So your check to see if an email address exists NEVER gets executed, then you blindly try to insert it anyways.

As well, this is **NOT** how you do this sort of check. Even if the code was properly structured, there's **NO** guarantee that some parallel script won't be able to insert that very same email address in the (short) interval between this script doing its `select` and then the `insert`.

You should do an unconditional insert, and check if it succeeded, e.g.

```
if ($_POST) {
    $sql = "INSERT ..."
    try {
       ...execute...
    catch (PDOException $e) {
       if ($e->getCode() == 1062) // duplicate key violation
          ... email is a dupe
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you have 2 and more unique constraints in one table how are going to find what a field raises the exception?

Comment: True enough, but since OP's only selecting the email field, I don't think it's a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to `if($_POST['email'] !=$_POST['email'])` line since this will always evaluate to `False` thus it will not even check if the email already exists in your DB.